# EC2 instance in VPC public DNS name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have an VPC instance created on AWS. But it doesn't have a public DNS value as opposed to my other instance which is a straight EC2 instance.

eg ec2-45-55-79-ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Is there a way to assign a "Public DNS" value like the one above for my VPC instance?

Cheers to anyone who knows!!

Comment: I think that the following might help: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreateVPCForELB.html

Comment: Elastic IP is probably the simplest way: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-ip-addressing.html#vpc-eip-overview
and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html

Comment: Does it not have a public DNS value or does it also not have a public ip?

Comment: @FredrickCheung I have a public IP which is an elastic IP. But I dont have a public DNS value and I'm wondering can I get one?

Answer (score 1):

The default public DNS name is assigned based on your VPC configuration. Make sure that the following settings are set in the VPC console (https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/):

1. DNS resolution and DNS hostnames attributes are set to True in your VPC
2. You have the DHCP options set with default provider AmazonProviderDNS. Something like: 
   `domain-name = ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
   domain-name-servers = AmazonProvidedDNS`

More details for DHCP Options Set configuration: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the instance is launched into a public subnet, and then you can assign an elastic IP.